# Where and how should I store a file with key & token on GitHub?

Tags: python, api, unit-testing, github

I have a folder with unit tests in Python for testing Trello API.
I created a separate file called `settings.py`, which contains my key and token:

```
key = my_key
token = my_token
```

I want to put this file in the same folder, where I have my unit tests.
So I would import `key` and `token` from 'settings' each time I run the test.

I don't know how to protect my `settings.py`, so it's not visible.
Is it where the `.gitignore` comes in? Or is there a better way to protect my file?

Comment: Definitely .gitignore it if it is sensitive information. You could then replace the sensitive info with some dummy information, then force push it with its dummy values to override the .gitignore entry.

Comment: Gitignore is probably the best idea, you know how to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.gitignore` file allows for ignoring files from commits. Files excluded by the file will be untouched by git, neither uploaded or overwritten.

To add a file to the `.gitignore` file, which exists in the base directory of any repo, follow instructions like the ones on the GitHub docs: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/.

1. If the file is already checked into git, (if unsure, run just in case) running `git rm --cached FILENAME` will 'un-check' it in.
2. For ignoring one specific file, putting its file path (relative to the repo folder) at the bottom of the file will ignore it.

ex.1 For a file at `/home/John/MyRepo/thing.txt`, adding the line `thing.txt` to the bottom of `/home/John/MyRepo/.gitignore` will ignore it.

ex.2 For a file at `/home/John/MyRepo/folder/thing.txt`, adding the line `folder/thing.txt` to the bottom of `/home/John/MyRepo/.gitignore` will ignore it.